# Oracle JET + ojSelect change Handler

Tags: oracle-jet

Below is the code snippet of view and viewModel from a JET application.

I am trying to update Member dropdown list based on house select option change.

Please need suggestion on where to add the code to update the observableArray of self.Member

```
<select data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect', value: houseVal}">
                <option value="A">Assembly</option>
                <option value="S">Senate</option>                    
            </select>
            <input id="text-input" aria-label="district" 
                   type="text"
                   data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect', 
            options: Members,
            value: selectVal}"/>
            <button data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton',label:'Search'},click:getData"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of `Members` based on `houseVal`, then you need to `subscribe` to `houseVal`.

```
var self = this;
self.houseVal = ko.observable();
self.Members = ko.observableArray();
self.selectVal = ko.observable();

self.houseVal.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if (newValue === 'A'){
        self.Members([{value: 'GB', label: 'George Bush'},
                      {value: 'MW',  label: 'Martin Woo'}]);
    }
    else {
        self.Members([{value: 'GB', label: 'Beorge Gush'},
                      {value: 'WM',  label: 'Wartin Moo'}]);
    }
});
```